# EntityManager auto wiring if I am using crudrepository

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, native, entitymanager

I have an interface that implements crudrepository. I am using @Query annotations.

I really need an entitymanager to build a native query. What should I do? Should I tear down the interface implementing crudrepository and extend from simplejparepository?

Please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an entityManager - @Query annotation has a nativeQuery parameter that allows you to do just that! Check [Spring Data documentation about it](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_native_queries) for more examples:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
```

If you still need to access the EM directly for some reason, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34876232/1563204 or at [Spring Data documentation for custom JPA repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.misc.jpa-context).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and those links! You solved my problem today